# Howto - Authenticating a calling assembly across a tcp/ip boundary

Tags: c#, authentication, pki, tcp

I have an server engine, which generally works in the server (imaginatively). But occasionaly it will be executing on a client, or occasionally on another server, and will be wanting to use this server to do some of extra/additional processing.

The link between will be protected by ssl/tls and certificates. So the communication will be secure, but i'm not sure that calling engine is my code.

How would you go about athenticating that engine.  What would Alice and Bob say on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find a 100% way to do this.

Since:

1. The code is running on the client
2. Then the code is available for disassembly
3. Then whatever security measures you have placed into the code running on the client, an attacker can circumvent

Basically, since Karl can phone up Alice and pretend to be Bob, by having Bob's voice, and knowing everything Bob knows (the disassembled code), then there is no way Alice can verify that it really is Bob, or just a very good impostor.

If you design your software so that it can only run on specific types of hardware, with [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) or similar technology, then you might have a chance, but *only* through software, you cannot create a 100% solution.

Even with a TPM-enabled solution, you could still risk the impostor circumventing it by sitting inbetween.

It all depends on what kind of attacks you want to prevent.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to proceed. I guess at the end of the day, the product is behind an enterprise firewall, controlled in a noc, with SLA's in place and additional hardened windows servers surrounding it. How much work/cost is involved in design/code/put a tpm solution in. Suppose it would depend on the attacks/vector. I'm looking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for this problem. You can't know for sure that the remote machine will not be suborned by an attacker, and thus you cannot be absolutely sure that remote code in communication with you is the code you originally intended to be communicating with you.

People use TPMs and similar mechanisms to try to do remote attestation of the trustworthiness of the remote hardware, but trying to do such things purely in software is hopeless as you cannot know what is running on the remote side. In the general case, given long enough an attacker can also suborn a TPM.